# How to add the same XML tags multiple times, with different content value in (c#) .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I am creating and API in .Net core using webservice .wsdl file, I have hardcoded the xml like below:
[image]

```
 XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(
                          "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Header/>\r\n<soapenv:Body>\r\n<MyServiceRequest>\r\n<ITEMSLIST>\r\n<ITEMS>\r\n<ID>$" +request.ID+"</ID>\r\n<NAME>" + request.NAME+ "</NAME>\r\n</ITEMS>\r\n</ITEMSLIST>\r\n</acc:MyServiceRequest>\r\n</soapenv:Body>\r\n</soapenv:Envelope>");

 var xmlRequestBody = xDocument.ToString();
```

Values are adding in array from this model:

```
Items[] request

public class Items
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }
```

I am adding values dynamically, for single value it is working fine, but when adding multiple values it is not working.
XML file is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header />
      <soapenv:Body>
        <acc:MyServiceRequest>
          <ITEMSLIST>
            <ITEMS>
              <ID>06285883</ID>
              <NAME>John</NAME>
            </ITEMS>
          </ITEMSLIST>
        </acc:MyServiceRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

for multiple values the xml should look like this, before sending the request. the values should be filled dynamically from the request model.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soapenv:Header />
      <soapenv:Body>
        <acc:MyServiceRequest>
          <ITEMSLIST>
            <ITEMS>
              <ID>06285883</ID>
              <NAME>John</NAME>
            </ITEMS>
             <ITEMS>
              <ID>06285231</ID>
              <NAME>Sara</NAME>
            </ITEMS>
          </ITEMSLIST>
        </acc:MyServiceRequest>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can anyone guide How I can **add multiple values in the same xml**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** I'm trying to give the main idea**

1. I just removed all those `\r\n`.
2. Found the `ITEMSLIST` element out side of the loop.
3. Iterat all items and for each one, make an `XElement` object and add it to `itemsList` element.
4. In the end, the result is in `xDocument` object.

```
private static XElement xDocument = XElement.Parse(
@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <MyServiceRequest>
        <ITEMSLIST>
        </ITEMSLIST>
     </MyServiceRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>");


public void Test()
{
    Items[] items = new Items[]
    {
        new Items { ID = "06285883", NAME = "John" },
        new Items { ID = "06285231", NAME = "Sara" }
    };

    var itemsList = xDocument.Descendants("ITEMSLIST").Single();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        XElement element = new XElement("ITEMS");
        element.Add(new XElement("ID", item.ID));
        element.Add(new XElement("NAME", item.NAME));

        itemsList.Add(element);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
}
```

Comment: Bundle of Thanks It worked for me, great

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267490/thanks-in-a-comment